# How to use a GitHub actions workflow in all organization repositories?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a GitHub action workflow that I want to be used on every repository in our company. but I dont want to manually copy the workflow into every repository. is there a way to make the workflow applied to every repository?

Comment: You can create a script that uploads the workflow file to every repository.

Comment: can you please elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: The script could have the workflow template inside it and add this file to each of your org repositories (creating the .github/workflows folder if it doesn't exist yet). You might achieve this using the Github API https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#contents with some user credential.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your workflow run another yml-file/workflow in a submodule that you add to every repository once. Once you have that you only need to edit that workflow in the submodule and it will change for all your repos.